# ISA Proxy server

Tags: 12.04, firefox, proxy, google-chrome

Have a proxy at work that runs Microsoft ISA. i used to be able to connect using 11.10 with firefox no problem at all. i could either put the settings in firefox or the settings in ubuntu network proxy settings.

this would give me a connection no problem ( slow due to the work network being really lame)

since i upgraded with 12.10 firefox just crashes if i have any proxy settings (manual added the proxy settings). if i connect to a diffrent network without the proxy settings it works fine and doesn't crash

i tried chrome to see if that would work... simular problem. chrome doesn't crash but is so slow it just times out all the time and can take 10min for a page to load....

not really sure where to go with this? i have tried a clean install of 12.04 on 2 diffrent computers and also both tried just upgrading from 11.10.

Only answer i can see at the moment is role back to 11.10 :(

i have tried all sorts like turning of IPv6 to see if that would make any diffrence but no joy... really am lost now.

whats weird is the repositys are also really really slow through 12.04. 50 megs took an hour to download (ISA server has Ubuntu rep servers enables without authenication).

really am lost

Comment: I've issue with ubuntu 12.04 under proxy. Browsers(firefox and chrome) freezes when i use proxy setting. but @Hannes Wagener your solution really helped me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem(after trying everything there is on the net).

After my own investigation I noticed (via a packet capture) that there is a continuous lookup for the host name(reverse) of the proxy server.

All I did to fix the problem was to add an entry to my host file for my prefered ISA proxy.   That solved the problem in an instant.  Try it yourself.

That is, I added an entry like the following in my host file (`/etc/hosts`):

```
192.168.199.199 proxy
```

Comment: I've issue with ubuntu 12.04 under proxy. Browsers(firefox and chrome) freezes when i use proxy setting. but @Hannes Wagener your solution really helped me.
Thanks